# Mouse click not working on open apps

Tags: mouse

I am having issues with 12.10.

The mouse seems to work on some parts of Ubuntu and not others. for example, I can open apps using the left home bar thing, and if they are full-screen, with the button, I can navigate through folders, but if I open a web browser, I cannot click on anything in the browser, though I can use the keyboard and tab around. If the web browser is also not full screen, and the close/min/max buttons are on the top right, in black, I cannot use them.

when this is the case, the mouse is not at all frozen. I can move the cursor freely, open new apps, navigate through Ubuntu, only cannot click in any open apps with the mouse.

There is nothing wrong with the mouse, as it works great on Windows, and I have tried both my RAT 7 and performance MX wireless mouses, to the same effect.

My hardware: P8Z77-V_LX mobo, i5 3570k, 16GB RAM (DDR3 1600Mhz), booted off Patriot Pyro SSD 120GB, integrated graphics 4000 (yeah, yeah, I'm getting something when I can afford it. built for upgradeability)

DualBoot Windows 7 Pro & Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: may be help [My mouse click function work wrongly after reinstall ubuntu 14.04.1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/552257/my-mouse-click-function-work-wrongly-after-reinstall-ubuntu-14-04-1/555232)

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced the same, but it happened when a game froze and I rebooted from the terminal.

The manual workaround is to switch to the text console with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and go back to X11 with Ctrl+Alt+F7. Someone else's answer, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar vague issues when using a Cyborg R.A.T. 3 mouse in Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome.

Initially I did not suspect the mouse, as it moved fine, I could click on some things (although not all), and some of the issues did not seem to be related to the mouse at all.

However, switching to a different mouse (basic 3-button Logitech) instantly solved all issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on a Samsung RV511 laptop, using USB mouses (2) and not using the touch pad whatsoever.

After opening up the laptop to replace the thermal paste on the processor, my mouse was working quite randomly, too. The right click never worked and, moments later, suddenly the previous right click actions worked on whatever the cursor was positioned. Also the focus between apps sometimes didn't change for the mouse actions, at times by working on another app on the background.

I think I solved my problem (at least it's working normally for now). I disconnected the left and right click from the integrated touch pad. Now my USB mouses work the right way, although I've lost the status lights (charging, processing, caps on/off, etc.).

Hope this helps.