# Strange mouse click behaviour after reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: unity, mouse

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 alongside Windows 8.1 and the only problem I had was that I wasn't able to boot Windows 8.1, because when I installed Ubuntu, I forgot to choose the EFI disk partition as the boot device. I reinstalled Ubuntu, and after reinstall I can enter Windows 8.1, but my mouse is not working properly in Ubuntu. It only works correctly when I click the top pannel, for example: log out, the calendar, etc, if I start any application, I cannot use the mouse left button or right button to close window, focus in text input box, switch tab, etc...

The mouse middle button works, and the mouse cursor can move correctly, and on web pages, mouseover effects work.

This issue only occurs with Unity desktop environment, the mouse click works correctly with gnome shell, but I would like to use Unity.

My mouse is USB. I use integrated graphic card hd3000.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the mouse issue was caused by some configuration files (I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04.1, but my home directory pointed to a separated home partition that was not formatted when reinstalling Ubuntu).

So I backed up all of the hidden files and hidden directories in the my home directory using `tar -czf cfg.backup.tar.gz ~/.*`, then I removed all the hidden files and hidden directories in the my home directory by `sudo rm -rf ~/.*`.

I restarted the computer, after I logged in, everything is ok! now, if you miss some custom configuration you has lost, you can find it from `cfg.backup.tar.gz`, use the one in the backup to replace the one in your home directory.

---

**Editor's Note:**

> **WARNING!** while removing offending config files is a useful technique, removing all hidden files and directories is not a good idea as many things will not work properly. A better approach might be to back up all your config files and try renaming or removing the likely suspects one by one (start with `~/.config` and if that doesn't work try `~/.local`). If you *really* feel you need to nuke the whole lot (highly unlikely) then you could make a new user, and copy the hidden files from the new user's home directory over those in your old home directory, for example.