# Ubuntu 16.04 - Mouse moves but cannot click

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Please help, I am having an issue with my mouse, and sometimes the keyboard.

- The mouse can move, but after opening some windows, I cannot click on particular things.
- Sometimes the keyboard will stop working also.
- And sometimes the keyboard and mouse start working again after clicking random things.
- Re-installed 16.04 a few times and the problem reoccurs, even just after installation.
- The mouse is a basic dell mouse that works on Windows fine.

Comment: it seems you may have some problems with the mouse itself(does it turns off in a specific mouse movement?) or problems with usb port itself.

Comment: It turns off after opening different windows in ubuntu, and all usb ports work fine on the mb. The PC is running windows 10 fine, and the mouse is a basic dell mouse. The mouse and the keyboard work fine.

Comment: i had same situation, but reversed(Linux - OK, Windows - Not) until i changed mouse.

Comment: In my case switching to a different mouse solved a number of issues [see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108037)

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same issue recently on ubuntu 18, dell inspiron 7559. My solution is as following:
show pointer devices with xinput

```bsh
$ xinput
```

disable them in order and try click

```bsh
$ xinput disable 1
```

when find the device causing issue, enable the devices disabled before

```bsh
$ xinput enable 1
```

Remember the device info. When same issue happens next time, try disabling the device.

Answer (score 0):

This has probably got something to do with your drivers. Change your display drivers to Nvidia proprietary drivers. Hopefully, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Why do you think, that graphical driver can be issue for mouse movement and clicking?

Comment: I installed the nvidia proprietary driver, but unfortunately it made no difference.